# How eccentric can a planet’s orbit be before it is uninhabitable?

Tags: planets, earth-like, terraforming

So, I am writing a list of criteria for wannabe terraformers so that they know at what point any of their pet projects can be considered truly habitable. This list covers everything from the necessary  atmospheric pressure and composition to minimum water levels and rotation periods. It also needs to cover orbital eccentricity, but I am not sure; how eccentric can a planet’s orbit be before it experiences radical fluctuations of temperature and is uninhabitable to Earth life?

Comment: What degree of detail are you looking for? The axiomatically simple answer would be "planets are not habitable if their orbit takes them outside of the habitable zone as defined by the local star".

Comment: @Dragongeek It also depends on the planet.   A larger planet with a thicker atmosphere and hydrosphere might be able to swing farther away from the local star that a lower mass planet that will lose its heat faster.

Comment: @Dragongeek I dunno, I feel like that's probably a soft rule. I could imagine a planet that develops a hibernation period as it goes out of the habitable zone, maybe. Within limits, anyway. All oceans freeze over: probably okay. All oxygen in the air freezes: probably less okay.

Comment: How do you define "habitable"?

Comment: How does perihelion vary with eccentricity? Depending on what life form you focus on, It may help to keep Earth life at an average 15°C, over at least the first few increasingly eccentric years to come.

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically it might be possible for a planet orbiting a variable star to have a relatively constant temperature if the planet was closest to the star when the star was dimmest, and farthest from the star when it was brightest.

But it seems extremely unlikely for such a planet to exist.

If you mean terraforming a planet to become habitable for Earth humans with human rquirements, you should check *Habitable Planets for Man*, stephen Dole, 1654.

https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/commercial_books/2007/RAND_CB179-1.pdf

Dole discusses orbital eccentricity on pages 66 to 67.

If you mean terraforming for liquid water using life in general, some of which can flourish in environments hostile to humans, it is possible that some planets could have atmospheres and hydrospheres that might maintain relatively constant tempereratures despite eccentric orbits and large changes in stellar radiation recived by the planet.

Answer (score 2):

On a first approximation, it depends on the central star and the extension of its goldilocks zone: this is usually a shell, and as long as you can fit the elliptical orbit of the planet into this shell, the planet should be habitable.

But since there is not a one size fits all extension of the goldilocks zone for every star, a single answer cannot be given.